# Using lambdas in c++11 visualstudio11 with winapi

Tags: winapi, c++11, lambda

Instead of

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, function, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I was interested in trying

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, [](LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE){ int x = 0; return x;}, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I get ERROR: No suitable conversion function from lambda []int (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)->int to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE exists.

Answer (score 2):

The signature on your lambda function is incorrect.  It needs to accept `void*` and return `DWORD`.  Try the following

```
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pStart = [](void* pValue) -> DWORD { int x = 0; return x; };
::CreateThread(NULL, NULL, pStart, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Note: I believe this will only work on Visual Studio 2012 and higher.  I do not believe lambda to function pointer conversions were implemented before then